# ExtJs: Does store need to be removed forcefully once the grid using it is destroyed?

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, store, destroy

In our application, we are having various windows which contain grid and their respective stores. General code structure of a window we have is as following:

```
function showWin(){
    var storeVar    =   //code for store
    var gridVar     =   //code for grid with store as storeVar
    var winVar      =   //code for window having gridVar as item
    winVar.show();
}
```

This showWin() function is being called say on a button click which displays the window.

**Now when this window is closed then it is destroyed along with its child item grid. But does this also destroy the store associated with the grid? I guess not.**

**Thus, if storeVar is not destroyed on closing of window (more precisely on destruction of grid) then should this be forcefully removed in order to reduce the extra baggage (as a new copy gets created everytime the function is called) from the memory? If yes, how?**

Thanks for any help in advance.

PS: We are using ExtJs ver 4.0.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked the same question in sencha forum and as per the answer received there, I guess that the store doesn't need to be destroyed forcefully as the garbage collector would itself take care of it. [More here.](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?191451-Does-store-need-to-be-removed-forcefully-once-the-grid-using-it-is-destroyed)

Updating the things here too, hoping it helps someone else looking for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't create store objects yourself. There is StoreManager class in ExtJs which handles all this in the background. You just access store objects by calling Ext.getStore('MyStore1').

And with this approach each store usually has only one instance in the memory. So you don't need to worry about destroying it either.

Comment: Could you please elaborate upon 'Usually you don't create store objects yourself'. When we create a grid, don't we create its store too?

Comment: Not manually. You just specify store: 'mystore' and StoreManager will create an object instance for you.

Comment: Thanks Sha. But here is a URL from examples at ExtJS website - http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/grid/array-grid.html - in this example, and to be precise, in every other example, you can find that store has been manually created (this can be checked in the js file of the example). Thus, is this not a correct way?

Comment: Yes and no. It's good for samples where they have local data stored. But if you're developing big MVC application - you will have special classes and files for each store and they will be created automatically. Very few Sencha examples are actually using their MVC pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the time Sha. Thus, when we create a grid and specify store:myStore then how would you suggest to add proxy, reader,  url and other stuff to the store? Just to add, not only in the grid, but also in the combos, the pattern used is to create a store as can be checked in the js file here - http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/form/combos.html

Comment: You would have store class where this all defined and assigned. Did you go through their MVC app sample?

Comment: Our app is not using MVC structure unfortunately. Are you suggesting that this would work fine only for MVC? Thus, what if the structure is the which has been shared in the question above. In that case, do we need to destroy the stores manually?

Comment: I still don't think so. Do you have remote or local store?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9412/discussion-between-netemp-and-sha)